# Highstock: Plot name labels

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using the Highstock and I've been reading the API documentation to look for the plot labeling however, was unsuccessful.
When I do something like

```
xAxis: {
               labels: {
               enabled: true,
               name: plot one name,
               floor: 0,
             }
           }
```

or

```
series: [{
data: XData,
name: plot one name
}
```

it does not give me the label at the bottom.

It works in the highchart, but highstock. Is there a documentation / APi to add plot label inside the graph ?

for example, in the following link of the highchart is the plot label of "tokyo" and "london" http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-labels

Comment: I think you are looking for the `legend`. Try `legend: { enabled: true }`.

Comment: @HalvorStrand thank you, that is correct

Comment: @HalvorStrand can you write that as an answer so I can checkmark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The labels you are looking for is called the legend ([API](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#legend.enabled)).

It is disabled by default in Highstock. You can enable it by adding this code:

```
legend: {
    enabled: true
}
```